# Creating Notifications onesignal not language

Tags: android, message, onesignal

I'm adding the push in an application already published, and I just wanted to change how to send the push without having to send a new update to the application. 
Today by amazon we send like this:

```
{"GCM": "{ "data": { "message": "teste" } }"}
```

And by your system send thus:

```
{"GCM": "{ "data": { "message": {en:"teste"} } }"}
```

Is it possible to send a json in this way?

```
{"GCM": "{ "data": { "message": "teste" } }"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to actual limitations of OneSignal, the default language is always *English ('en').*

You can check more details in its documentation here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/language-localization